# Hashing in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I want to hash some text along with the value of a table column in mysql. I am doing this but it gives a different value on comparing to which i expect.

```
SELECT SHA1('a='+p.ItemID) FROM Items p WHERE p.ItemID = 412
```

The above query gives some different result, but i need the results which the below query yields:

```
SELECT SHA1('a=412')
```

Why do the results differ?
Please help.
Are these two queries not the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT('a=', p.ItemID)) FROM Items p WHERE ItemID = 412
```

Comment: BTW: I think yours is broken ;) (you missed the p)

Comment: Have an upvote, my like-mindend friend with the faster trigger.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT('a=',p.ItemID)) FROM Items p WHERE p.ItemID = 412
```

See this page in the MySQL manual for more on [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), which is different from [+, the addition operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus). This is why your results differ.